# Get Pretrained Inception v3 model from Open Images dataset working on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I tried a while to get the pretrained model working on android. The problem is, I only got the ckpt and meta file for the pretrained net. In my opinion I need the .pb for the android app. So I tried to convert the given files to an .pb file.

Therefore I tried the freeze_graph.py but without succes. So I used the example code from https://github.com/openimages/dataset/blob/master/tools/classify.py and modified it to store a pb. file after loading

```
if not os.path.exists(FLAGS.checkpoint):
  tf.logging.fatal(
      'Checkpoint %s does not exist. Have you download it? See tools/download_data.sh',
      FLAGS.checkpoint)
   g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  input_image = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
   processed_image = PreprocessImage(input_image)

  with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v3_arg_scope()):
    logits, end_points = inception.inception_v3(
        processed_image, num_classes=FLAGS.num_classes, is_training=False)

    predictions = end_points['multi_predictions'] = tf.nn.sigmoid(
       logits, name='multi_predictions')
  init_op = control_flow_ops.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                             tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                             data_flow_ops.initialize_all_tables())
  saver = tf_saver.Saver()
  sess = tf.Session()
  saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint)

  outpt_filename = 'output_graph.pb'
  #output_graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
  output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), ["multi_predictions"])
  with gfile.FastGFile(outpt_filename, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Now my problem is that I have the .pb file but I don't have any opinion what is the input node name and I am not sure if `multi_predictions` is the right output name. In the example android app I have to specify both. And the android app crashed with:

```
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:138 Could not create Tensorflow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs.
```

I don't know if there are more problem by trying to fix the .pb problem. Or if anyone knows a better way to port the ckpt and meta files to a .pd file in my case or knows a source for the final file with input and ouput names please give me a hint to complete this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the optimize_for_inference.py script to strip out the unused nodes in your graph. "decodeJpeg" is not supported on Android -- pixel values should be fed in directly. ClassifierActivity.java has more detail about the specific nodes to use for inception v3.

Comment: Sorry for being busy a while. Your are absolutely right with your tip for using optimize_for_inference.py and I could use "Mul" as input node. many thanks

Comment: Hi @lampep how are you preprocessing your images? I'm trying to run this on ios and the same predictions are repeated. I followed your code, generated an optimised graph but the predictions aren't working right. Thanks!